# Select data from 2 tables, UNPIVOT first table and join it with other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have 2 tables in SQL, namely **Pets** and **Customers**

**Pets** table:

| Pet ID | PetType |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Dog |
| 02 | Cat |
| 03 | Mouse |
| 04 | Fish |

**Customer** table:

| CustID | CustName | PetType | IsPet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Cust1 | Dog | Y |
| 02 | Cust2 | Cat | Y |
| 03 | Cust3 | Dog | Y |
| 04 | Cust4 | Fish | Y |
| 05 | Cust5 | Mouse | Y |
| 06 | Cust6 | Dog | Y |

I need to select the records in such a way that the list of Customer are joined with pivoted columns for the pets.
For example, the result should be:

| CustID | CustName | Dog | Cat | Mouse | Fish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Cust1 | Yes |  |  |  |
| 02 | Cust2 |  | Yes |  |  |
| 03 | Cust3 | Yes |  |  |  |
| 04 | Cust4 |  |  |  | Yes |
| 05 | Cust5 |  |  | Yes |  |
| 06 | Cust6 | Yes |  |  |  |

Any advice or help for the SQL query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know the columns in the final table (i.e. they come from the first table), then you will need dynamic SQL.

Comment: This is a pivot, not an unpivot. A Pivot transforms rows into columns, using aggregation, where as an unpivot transforms columns into rows (and doesn't require aggregation).

Answer (score 2):

You can use such a query in order to create all animals list inserted into the table dynamically  :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([PetType]),',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [PetType] 
                        FROM [Customer] ) C );
SELECT @cols;
SET @query = 
  N'SELECT *  
      FROM [Customer]
     PIVOT 
     (
         MAX(IsPet) FOR [PetType] IN (' + @cols + N')
     ) AS p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e50626581020fffe408589d6e40f952)</kbd>

If bringing the literal `Y` as `Yes` matters, then use a subquery along with a conditional such as

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([PetType]),',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [PetType] 
                        FROM [Customer] ) C );

SET @query = 
  N'SELECT *  
      FROM ( SELECT (CASE WHEN [IsPet]=''Y'' THEN ''Yes'' END) AS [IsPet],
                    [CustID], [CustName],[PetType]
               FROM [Customer] ) AS c
     PIVOT 
     (
       MAX([IsPet]) FOR [PetType] IN (' + @cols + N')
     ) AS p'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=deef24d07afc18bd183cb1101257781f)</kbd>

*In any case, `[Pets]` table is not needed.*